# Как можно сделать gui на python по примеру

Tags: python, gui

подскажите пожалуйста на чем можно построить интерфейс по примеру: 
[image: пример того, что планирую сделать]

Я не знаю как в PyQT или Tkinter(или есть другой вариант) сделать несколько блоков в одной строке с возможностью добавления информации в каждом блоке построчно и изменением цвета строк/текста и прошу Вашего совета

Сейчас все крутиться на raspberry в браузере работает видео с камеры и это крайне не стабильно, браузер часто показывает: aw swap
Хочется сделать более стабильное решение

Comment: Для Qt есть `qt designer`, который позволяет накидать интерфейс и посмотреть на его текстовую реализацию. Даже был конвертер для Python, когда я последний раз с этим сталкивался.

Comment: Благодарю, иду гуглить

Comment: PyQt5 вам в помощь. `pip install PyQt5` + `pip install pyqt5-tools`